# Clang-format brace on newline after function and initialization

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm using Clang-format, with a configuration that has been made a while ago.

I noticed that the style for initialization of variables kept the braces on the same line as the arguments, but I'd like it to close on a new line (if the arguments also have been put on a new line).
This is how it looks:

```cpp
std::string const long_init{
    "Smartasdasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasglove"};
    
some_class some_class_var{
    long_arg_name_1, long_arg_name_2, long_arg_name_3, long_arg_name_4};
```

This is how I'd like it to look:

```cpp
std::string const long_init{
    "Smartasdasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasglove"
};
    
some_class some_class_var{
    long_arg_name_1, long_arg_name_2, long_arg_name_3, long_arg_name_4
};
```

I tried looking through the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), but I can't seem to find the right parameter to tune.

Anyone knows what setting controls this?

Answer (score 1):

According to clang-format documentation: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#alignafteropenbracket

Set `AlignAfterOpenBracket` to `BlockIndent`:

```
AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent
```

It seems won't work if your code like:

```
VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {
        .commandBufferCount = 1,
        .pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffer};
```

Just need to add a comma after the last member of structure:

```
VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {
        .commandBufferCount = 1,
        .pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffer,};
```

Then it works:

```
VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {
        .commandBufferCount = 1,
        .pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffer,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

BreakBeforeBraces (BraceBreakingStyle) clang-format 3.7 ¶
The brace breaking style to use.

Possible values:
BS_Attach (in configuration: Attach) Always attach braces to surrounding context.

```cpp
        namespace N {
        enum E {
          E1,
          E2,
        };

        class C {
        public:
          C();
        };

        bool baz(int i) {
          try {
            do {
              switch (i) {
              case 1: {
                foobar();
                break;
              }
              default: {
                break;
              }
              }
            } while (--i);
            return true;
          } catch (...) {
            handleError();
            return false;
          }
        }

        void foo(bool b) {
          if (b) {
            baz(2);
          } else {
            baz(5);
          }
        }

        void bar() { foo(true); }
        } // namespace N
```

That's from the docs, hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately this does not help :( 
(I use Stroustrup, and tried changing to Attach and others).
This seems to only affect namespaces, functions and classes, not variables.